# How does SpaceX get through regulatory issues so quickly?

Tags: spacex, nasa, crewed-spaceflight, regulatory

"Regulatory" isn't the right word, but I don't know what is.

For example, SpaceX seemed to be able to prove to NASA's satisfaction that they were sufficiently safe to use for crewed launches in 2020. The very little I know of SpaceX's processes and approaches suggest that they would not have aligned to NASA's systems engineering process very well, so how were they able to convince NASA they were ready for manned flight so quickly?

I am especially looking for a process description here.

Comment: The CCDev (commercial crew development) process was based on the COTS process that preceded it.  There were still years of meetings doing requirements development (I was in the rendezvous ones alongside NASA EG and others), and an extended feedback loop and iteration between SpaceX and NASA.  I'll try to figure out a way to put together a proper answer; it seems like [at least some of the documents](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/api/citations/20150010757/downloads/20150010757.pdf) are public, though imo the most important one, SSP 50808, is ITAR controlled :(

Comment: I wouldn't call it "quickly" as SpaceX was founded 20 years ago. The company has been quite Agile from the start. It took a good amount of time for SpaceX to convince NASA that Agile was a "good thing". NASA on the other hand had expected a waterfall model, even though NASA knows waterfall does not work.

Comment: Many, many good things have been delivered using waterfall @DavidHammen, including Apollo.

Comment: @ErinAnne I would very much like to read that answer. That spec is a great example: I would expect demonstrating compliance with it to be a significant undertaking. I also would be surprised if mere spec compliance satisfied whatever safe-for-flight process NASA uses. If there is a good point of contact for requesting the 50808 (not familiar with it) and that's the meat of the answer, I can send a request offline that unambiguously complies with ITAR.

Comment: "in 2020"...that was years later than originally planned. NASA was fretting about things like the COPVs and the load-and-go launch process literally for years, got way behind on processing paperwork due to being underfunded by a Congress hostile to Commercial Crew, and specified requirements for things like parachute hardware that led to major part shortages due to Orion, Starliner, and Dragon competing for the same parts, delaying their test programs. SpaceX does move relatively quickly at evaluating issues and qualifying solutions, but I don't think this is a good example.

Comment: @fectin ultimately, spec-compliance (really requirements-compliance) is the thing.  From 4.1 of CCT-REQ-1130, which I linked above, "Commercial Providers are responsible for verification planning and the performance of verification activities as specified in this document and in SSP 50808. The Commercial Providers will produce verification evidence for compliance with all applicable requirements."  That sounds really generic, but the verification is what shows NASA you can conduct crews and cargo in space.

Comment: @fectin There's an issue beyond being qualified to handle ITAR data in a general sense, which is "need to know." The rationale is that there's not a much of a difference between knowing how to launch and land a civilian spacecraft and knowing how to launch and land an intercontinental ballistic missile, and there's not much of a difference between knowing how to slowly rendezvous with the ISS and knowing how to violently rendezvous with (i.e., destroy) an enemy spacecraft. Launch, landing, and rendezvous are about as dual use as technology can get.

Answer (score 2):

First, it is because the Falcon 9 have a good track record. Much of regulation is basically convincing a whole lot of people that we know what we're doing and we're not going to cause a problem for you. By 2020, SpaceX had been fighting through what they perceived to be mostly useless bureaucratic regulations. SpaceX had a pretty good track record of 67 straight success with the Falcon 9 and had done the CRS and COTS program. During those programs they had only one failure, back in 2015, so they started off with a higher level of trust. By contrast, take Starship. Look at how much regulation issues that is facing. I won't go into it here, but you can search up "Why hasn't start gotten an FAA launch license?".

Additionally, one test flight is not exactly what happened here. While Dragon is different, the CRS and COTS program missions were all test flights of a sort. For the launcher, all 84 (85 counting the AMOS-6 on ground failure) missions were tests. The only thing Crew Demo-1 was testing in one flight was the things required for humans.

Finally, one test flight isn't all that crazy either for a reliable launcher:

1. Starliner only planned to have one test flight (then the test flight failed).
2. The SLS only had one test flight before it will have crew.
3. The shuttle had 0 uncrewed test flights (I won't go into why).
4. The Titan II GTV (the Gemini vehicle) only had 1 test flight to verify it's safety for crew (the other was solely to test a heat shield)

I could continue, but you get the point. This isn't unheard of.

Comment: Unfortunately, I think this is a great answer for a different question. I really do want to understand SpaceX's process here, and am far less interested in whether that process was appropriate or safe.

Comment: Unfortunately, the exact processes are unlikely to be publicly available @fectin

Comment: @fectin I agree with Starship is go for launch: Their process gives them a competitive advantage and hence SpaceX treats it as a trade secret. SpaceX's IV&V contractor knows their processes, as does NASA, but since it is a trade secret, you will not find it. I work for SpaceX's IV&V contractor, which also is the same contractor NASA uses for certifying that SpaceX has done the right thing. We are firewalled to the max. As I know other companies trade secrets, I cannot work with either of those two groups. That means I am free to say what is in the media, which is that SpaceX is very Agile.

Comment: I think my answer is the best that is known, but if I am wrong, please tell me (with a source) @fectin

Comment: This answer needs sources badly.  It's also incorrect about "only one failure" for Falcon 9; CRS-7 exploded during ascent.  That was the 2015 failure; AMOS-6 was in 2016.

Comment: AMOS-6 was not part of the CRS or COTS program @ErinAnne

Comment: While not part of CRS, AMOS-6 occurred between CRS-9 and CRS-10, and 100% affected the amount of trust NASA had in SpaceX.

Comment: Not disagreeing, but my claim is that the CRS and COTS programs only had one failure and that showed trust. Later I talk about track record as a whole @ErinAnne

Comment: The Shuttle did have a crewed test flight. The reason it had no uncrewed test flights was that the Shuttle needed a human pilot to land. The Shuttle did not have an automated landing capability.

Comment: I know, I say I won't go into that as it is getting off the orginial topic. Demo-2 is a crewed test flight as well @DavidHammen